# Set sysdate as List parameter in oracle reports

Tags: oraclereports

I am trying to set `SYSDATE-1` in list parameter in oracle report. Input mask is `mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS` 
now how can I set in the list parameter as `SYSDATE-1 00:00:00`. When I try to set it is throwing as error.

`value does not match with the input mask` please suggest how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Let pretend that sysdate is `2014.12.19 18:26:58`:

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')              --12/19/2014 18:26:58

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')          --12/18/2014 18:26:58

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'mm/dd/yyyy')                     --12/18/2014

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')   --12/18/2014 00:00:00

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1), 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')   --12/18/2014 00:00:00

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1, 'mm/dd/yyyy')||' 00:00:00'        --12/18/2014 00:00:00

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1)||' 00:00:00'                      --2014.12.18 00:00:00

Not sure for this one
TO_CHAR(ROUND(SYSDATE) - 1, 'mm/dd/yyyy  HH24:MI:SS'') --12/18/2014 00:00:00
```